# What C++ compiler would compile without mistakes source codes of this publication for game developing?

Tags: c++, 3d

http://cws.cengage.co.uk/rautenbach/students/ancillary_content/C++.pdf
I tried with different compilers but I received many errors

Comment: Need more info. As it stands, the question is too broad and is unclear, to me, what you are asking. Please give an example of code that doesn't compile and take it from there.

Comment: The book seems incomplete. Also I consider using gotos a very bad practice and they write about it.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the book:

> The examples provided in this book are 100% cross platform and will compile on any ANSI compiler. All the C++ examples were tested on Linux and Windows XP/Vista via the MinGW compiler and Microsoft Visual Studio 2005.

Note that they recommend a 10 year old compiler, this from a book teaching cutting edge technology -- GPU programming. Consider throwing it out.

Answer (score 0):

For what I see you need Visual C++ from Visual Studio 2008 or higher and the DirectX SDK.